# Слияние объекта через оператор оператор spread

Tags: javascript, объекты

```
console.log(
  merge(
{
  name: 'John',
     age: 22,
},
{
  surname: 'Klein',
  age: 20,
  profession: 'student',
},
    {
  profession: 'frontend developer',
  country: 'USA',
}
);

// {
//   name: 'John',
//   surname: 'Klein',
//   age: 20,
//   profession: 'frontend developer',
//   country: 'USA',
// }
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как слить эти обьекты  в один. Каждый последующий объект при совпадении ключей должен иметь больший приоритет над предыдущим. Использовать оператор spread

Comment: допиши этот оператор перед объектами

Answer (score 1):

Допустим есть 3 объекта:

```
let obj1 = {
  name: 'John',
     age: 22,
};
let obj2 = {
  surname: 'Klein',
  age: 20,
  profession: 'student',
};
let obj3 = {
  profession: 'frontend developer',
  country: 'USA',
};
```

Применим оператор `spread`, где каждый последующий объект перекрывает свойства предыдущего:

```
console.log({...obj1, ...obj2, ...obj3})
```